# Keras Implementation of a neural network found on a paper

Tags: neural-networks, python, keras

I am trying to implement a neural network I found on an open access paper as I have a similar problem and I am struggling with it. I am using tensorflow.keras for the implementation.

Here is the paper: https://www.mdpi.com/2072-4292/13/19/3800/xml

1. The authors work with data of size 100x100x100x2. My data are of size 128x128x128x1, so I only have one channel (real data, instead of complex like the authors which they divide into the two channels).
2. The authors assign S1 = C1/2. In my case, for the first block I put both equal to 1 as my C1 is = 1.
3. The authors use "max pooling layers of sizes 2 and 5 in turn". I choose sizes 2 and 4 as my input size is 128.
4. In my case, as my output size is 128x128x128x1, I added a final convolution stage to go back to this image size.

I have some issues with their description, and in particular figure 3 of their paper.

1. If over they blocks they put the output size of the block as they write, I don't get how they go from size 25x25x25x12 to size 5x5x5x24. I assume a pool block is missing in the figure.
2. I don't know what is the number of filters for the transpose convolutions in the decoder side.

Is my implementation correct? Is the final convolution layer I added creating problems? Do you suggest to work with data with two channels (with the imaginary one only containing zeros) to avoid using this layer?

```
def fire(x, S1, E, strides):
x = layers.Conv3D(S1, (1, 1, 1), strides, padding="same")(x)

x1 = layers.Conv3D(E, (1, 1, 1), strides=1, padding="same")(x)
x2 = layers.Conv3D(E, (3, 3, 3), strides=1, padding="same")(x)
x =  tf.keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=-1)([x1, x2])

return x

def fire_UNET(channels = 1):

#down
layer_conc = []
inputs = layers.Input(shape=(128, 128, 128, channels))
layer_conc.append(inputs)

# A
x = fire(inputs, 1, 3, strides = 1)
print(tf.shape(x))
x = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling3D(1, strides=2, padding="same")(x)
print(tf.shape(x))
layer_conc.append(x)

# B
x = fire(x, 3, 6, strides = 1)
print(tf.shape(x))
x = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling3D(1, strides=2, padding="same")(x)
print(tf.shape(x))
layer_conc.append(x)


# C    
x = fire(x, 6, 12, strides = 1)
print(tf.shape(x))
x = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling3D(1, strides=4, padding="same")(x)
print(tf.shape(x))

# D
x = layers.Conv3DTranspose(12, (3,3,3), strides=4, padding="same")(x)
print(tf.shape(x))
x = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=-1)([x, layer_conc[2]])
print(tf.shape(x))   
x = fire(x, 12,6, strides = 1)    
print(tf.shape(x))


# E
x = layers.Conv3DTranspose(6, (3,3,3), strides=2, padding="same")(x)
print(tf.shape(x))
x = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=-1)([x, layer_conc[1]]) 
print(tf.shape(x))   
x = fire(x, 6, 3, strides = 1)    
print(tf.shape(x))

# F
x = layers.Conv3DTranspose(1, (3,3,3), strides=2, padding="same")(x)
print(tf.shape(x))
x = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=-1)([x, layer_conc[0]]) 
print(tf.shape(x))
x = layers.Conv3D(1, (1, 1, 1), strides=1, padding="same")(x)
print(tf.shape(x))



outputs = x
return k.Model(inputs, outputs)
```